# JavaScript forEach Syntax and length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, refactoring

I'm looping through entire cars array and looking at counting number of objects that do not have class "filtered-out". Is it possible to simplify this syntax? I know in jQuery you can do something like this with elements:

```
        $("element").hasClass("filtered-out").length;
```

**My code:**

```
        var available_cars = 0;
        cars.forEach(function(element) {
            if (!element.hasClass("filtered-out"))
                available_cars++;
        });
```

Comment: You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`classList().contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Investigate Array.prototype.filter() it was meant to accomplish your goal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: i dont think there is a better way.  I think you're good!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter`:

```
var available_cars = cars.filter(function(car) { return !car.hasClass("filtered-out"); }).length;
```

That's more concise with an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
var available_cars = cars.filter(car => !car.hasClass("filtered-out")).length;
```

If you can make `cars` a jQuery object instead of an array (you seem to be using it as an array in your question), it would be:

```
var available_cars = cars.filter(":not(.filtered-out)").length;
```

---

The question treats `cars` as an array (`cars.forEach`) but treats the individual elements as jQuery objects (`element.hasClass`), so that's what I did in the first snippet above. It's odd, though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much TJ! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this without jQuery

```
const cars = document.querySelectorAll('.cars');
const carFilter = (car) => car.classList.contains('filtered-out');
const available_cars = [...cars].filter(carFilter);
console.log(available_cars.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with Mr. Crowder's answer, you could also use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in the following way:

```
cars.reduce((a, car) => { if(!car.hasClass("filtered-out")) {a++}; return a; }, 0);
```

Or, "minified":

```
cars.reduce((a, car) => !car.hasClass("filtered-out") && a++, 0);
```

This will also return the number of cars missing the class "filtered-out". If the elements aren't jQuery Objects, you'll need to add an extra `$()` around the `car` variable:

```
cars.reduce((a, car) => { if(!$(car).hasClass("filtered-out")) {a++}; return a; }, 0);
```